# ember: TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying set a value into `userSessionStorage`, when i am accessing it from the authenticate() function it seems to work correctly.

However, it is not working in the .then() promise.

app/controllers/show.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import { storageFor } from 'ember-local-storage';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  session: Ember.inject.service('session'),

  userSessionStorage: storageFor('user'),

  authenticator: 'authenticator:custom',

  actions: {
    authenticate: function() {
      var credentials = this.getProperties('identification', 'password');
      // ok
      this.set('userSessionStorage.username', credentials.identification);

      this.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:custom', credentials)
        .then(function(){

          // error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
          this.set('userSessionStorage.username', credentials.identification);

        })
        .catch((message) => {
          console.log("message: " + message);

          this.controller.set('loginFailed', true);
        });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Rewrite the function you are passing to `then` as an arrow function which maintains the surrounding value of `this`. Or capture this value of `this` at the top of the `authenticate` method with `const self = this;` and then use `self.set`.

Comment: @torazaburo you are good :) can you pls put this as an answer so that i can put it as the correct answer?

Comment: Why not setting `userSessionStorage.username` in your authenticator ?

Comment: @j-samah can you please elaborate, maybe can u put it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all you need to do is changing the following line:

```
 this.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:custom', credentials)
        .then(function(){....}
```

to using fat arrow notation as follows:

```
 this.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:custom', credentials)
        .then(()=>{....}
```

so that `this` context within the promise context will be your controller. See [following](https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-concise-syntax-javascript/) for more about ES6 arrow functions.

Answer (score 1):

It's based on my own code, so you might need to adapt it. But in your authenticator, your `authenticate` function may look like this :

```
# authenticator

authenticate(credentials) {
  const { identification, password } = credentials;
  const data = JSON.stringify({
    auth: {
      email: identification,
      password
    }
  });

  const requestOptions = {
    url: this.tokenEndpoint,
    type: 'POST',
    data,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json'
  };

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ajax(requestOptions).then((response) => {
      // Set your session here
    }, (error) => {
      run(() => {
        reject(error);
      });
    });
  });
},
```